# https tomcat opens on https://localhost:8443 but not using ip https://10.217.14.97:8443

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I have successfully configured secure https on tomcat.When I start the server and got to 
`https://localhost:8443` I can  see the tomcat web page open.But when I change the localhost string to ip address  `https://10.217.14.97:8443` it wont work.
My environment uses proxy ip address.So from the Lan settings when I uncheck "Use proxy server" and check mark "Automatically detect settings"
`https://10.217.14.97:8443` opens the apache webpage and it works.
The problem is I cant use https secure server with proxy settings.
I have put following lines of code in server.xml of tomcat for proxy settings.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="C:/Users/kh812917/.keystore"
           keystorePass="hamdulay"
           keyPass="hamdulay" proxyName="puneproxy.igate.com" proxyPort="8080"/>
```

proxyName and proxyPort attributes in Connector tag.
But it seems to be not working.
Please help me resolve the issue for using https secure on tomcat with proxy settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err, `localhost` is `127.0.0.1`. It's not accessible via `10.217.14.97`. If you wanted it to listen at `10.217.14.97,` specify that instead of `localhost.`

Comment: Thanks @EJP. 10.217.14.97 is my machine IP Address. Yes I want to listen at 10.217.14.97, where to specify this?